# 1 Question in properties related to binary hamming codes

Tags: coding-theory

I am studying Hamming codes from Xing and Ling and I have 2 questions in proposition 5.3.6.

Consider the following image:[image]

[image]

> Question: In proof of (ii) I am not able to understand the logic given in the proof behind the dimension being $2^r -1-r$ ie why parity check matrix is r $\times(2^r -1)$ matrix?

Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this might be of help. How does one construct a binary Hamming code? One picks a number $r$. Then they construct a $r \times (2^r-1)$ matrix $\mathbf{H}$ (we have $2^r-1$ and not $2^r$ because we want to avoid the codeword with all zeroes) with the columns to be binary representations of $1,2, \ldots, 2^{r-1}$. Then, notice that $\{x \mid \mathbf{H}x^T=0\}$ is a linear code of dimension $(2^r-1)-r$. This matrix $\mathbf{H}$ is the parity check matrix of the binary Hamming code of length $2^r-1$ and dimension $2^r-1-r$.